# Optimized way to check the value of a variable with enum members value

Tags: c++, c, enums

Hello I have the code below:

```
enum {a, b, c, d, ..., z} abc;

int main()
{
  int val = 20;
  if (val == a || val == b ||val == c||val == d..... || val == z)
  {
    /*Do something*/
  }
}
```

Is there any other way so that we can skip the `OR` operation because if there are 1000s of enum members then how can we do ahead with checking with all members.
Please help.

Comment: `if (val >= a || val <= z) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: @jrok: If `a = 1` , and `d = 20` then?

Comment: Your posted code is incorrect. It applies a bitwise "or" to the values `a`, `b`, `c`, ... and compares `val` to the result. (And the correct declaration for `main` is `int main(void)` for C, `int main()` for C++.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for identifying typo.

Comment: @Rasmi then what? I don't understand your question. EDIT: Ah yes, you mean if the values are not sequential. Well then, you've got no choice but to test each one of them :) (unless there's some other pattern you can count on)

Comment: @jrok: In that case how to solve solve them

Comment: That's still incorrect. It still compares `val` to a single value, which is now the result of a *logical* "or" of those 26 values. You're looking for something equivalent to `if (val == a || val == b || ... || val == z)`, right?

Comment: @KeithThompson : I did the change....

Comment: Better, but now you're just comparing to 4 values rather than 26. I don't know if that's significant.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sorry, I made the changes in a haste that is why

Comment: Optimized as in performance?  Or less code?

Comment: Maybe a switch statement? `switch (val) {case a: case b: ... case z: /*Do something*/}`. I've always thought that the compiler will optimize this by finding patterns in the adjoining cases, but I may be wrong.

Comment: One convention is to add two extra elements representing the beginning (typically 0) and end (typically the value of the last element plus one). This can be done by ending a sequential enum with `kEnd`, and `kBegin = 0`. That way you can perform the check using `if (x >= kBegin && x < kEnd) ...`, without having to worry about updating lots of code, if the content of the enum should change in the future.

Answer (score 5):

A modern compiler should just be able to optimize such code if, as in your case, the value of the expression is known at compile time. For readability and error checking I think that using a `switch` would be better:

```
switch (val)  {
 case a:;
 case b:;
 ....
 // your code goes here
}
```

As said, performance wise there shouldn't be much difference, the compiler will transform this to a table lookup (or other clever things) if appropriate or completely optimize it out if `val` is known at compile time.

But you can have the advantage of error checking compilers, here. If you don't have a `default` case, most compilers will warn you if you omit one of the enumeration constants. Also I think that this is clearer, since it doesn't repeat the evaluation of `val` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

other(faster) solution will be the following

```
bool isInenum (int val)
{
    bool retVal = false
        switch(val)

    {
        case a:
        case b:
        case c:
        case d:
            {
                retVal = true;
            }

    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since enumerator values are assigned sequentially, putting an if statement like this would be enough:

if(val<=z)

Comment: sequential value for enum is not a rule you can have enum{a=1;b=4;c=34..}abc; which is valid in c++

Comment: of course. but, in the example, they are assigned sequentially.

Comment: @AdrianHerea: And equally valid C, but it's relevant only if the enumeration type is defined that way.

Comment: @milistroke: I asked the same question to Jork above. if `a=1` and `d = 20`. Then how can we go ahead with optimized code?

Comment: it won't work on non-sequential values. however, if you use an integer array instead of an enumerator, you can perform a binary search operation on the array with O(logn) time complexity. So, if there are 1024 values on the array, the algorithm will only make 10 comparisons to find out whether the value exists in the array or not. But the array should be sorted. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map in C++. With a map you can write a compact test without the numerous `==` and `||`.

But you first need to initialize a map and I'm not sure if you can do this initialization in a compact way for an arbitrary enum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

enum abc { a = 1, b = -1, c = 3, d = 0 };

int main()
{
  map<int, int> m;
  m[a] = m[b] = m[c] = m[d] = 1;
  cout << "b is " << ((m.find(b) == m.end()) ? "NOT " : "") << "in m" << endl;
  cout << "3 is " << ((m.find(3) == m.end()) ? "NOT " : "") << "in m" << endl;
  cout << "10 is " << ((m.find(10) == m.end()) ? "NOT " : "") << "in m" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/tihqq)):

```
b is in m
3 is in m
10 is NOT in m
```